# Creating Views in PHP - Best Practice

Tags: php, templates, xhtml, separation-of-concerns

I am working on a website with 2 other developers. I am only responsible to creating the views.

The data is available in an object, and I have getters to read the data then create XHTML pages.

What is the best practice to do this, without using any template engine?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: why you don't want to use any template language?

Comment: PHP can be used as a templating language itself, for this you might need short tags turned on (not necessarily, but it is less writing then).

Comment: @baz: Sure. You can write great websites in Assembler, too.

Comment: are you using a framework or homebrew?

Comment: @nikic I always assumed that PHP's short tags (and the alternative syntaxes for all control structures) were there to offer templating use.

Comment: @nikic Have you tried? It's such a buzz.

Comment: @nikic - you must be awarded the Golden Globe. :P

Comment: @zaf: The "can" was more a "can theoretically" and the "great websites" was more like "Hello World websites". Though I just googled and didn't find even that :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want to use a templating engine, you can make use of PHP's basic templating capabilities.

Actually, you should just write the HTML, and whenever you need to output a variable's value, open a PHP part with `<?php` and close it with `?>`. I will assume for the examples that `$data` is your data object.

For example:

```
<div id="fos"><?php echo $data->getWhatever(); ?></div>
```

Please note that, all PHP control structures (like `if`, `foreach`, `while`, etc.) also have a syntax that can be used for templating. You can look these up in their PHP manual pages.

For example:

```
<div id="fos2">
<?php if ($data->getAnother() > 0) : ?>
    <span>X</span>
<?php else : ?>
    <span>Y</span>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

If you know that short tag usage will be enabled on the server, for simplicity you can use them as well (not advised in XML and XHTML). With short tags, you can simply open your PHP part with `<?` and close it with `?>`. Also, `<?=$var?>` is a shorthand for echoing something.

First example with short tags:

```
<div id="fos"><?=$data->getWhatever()?></div>
```

---

You should be aware of where you use line breaks and spaces though. The browser will receive the same text you write (except the PHP parts). What I mean by this:

Writing this code:

```
<?php
    echo '<img src="x.jpg" alt="" />';
    echo '<img src="y.jpg" alt="" />';
?>
```

is not equivalent to this one:

```
<img src="x.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="y.jpg" alt="" />
```

Because in the second one you have an actual `\n` between the `img` elements, which will be translated by the browser as a space character and displayed as an actual space between the images if they are inline.

Comment: This is the way it should be done in my opinion. In fact, the use of template systems is out of date to be honest. The downfall of a template system is that, yes , you wrote it, and you know how to work it, but what happens when you hire a new developer? He now has to read your code AND learn your template system.

Comment: @Dalton There are widespread templating systems like Smarty.

Comment: why are short tags not advised in XHTML?

Comment: @binaryLV XHTML is basically an XML document. Specifying the XML header (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`) will conflict with PHP's short tags. If you know what you're doing, there will be no problem, but you should be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate file to read the data:

```
<?php
 if ($foo == False)
  {
  $bar = 1;
  }
 else
  {
  $bar = 0;
  }
?>
```

Then reference the resulting state in the HTML file:

```
require 'logic.php';

<html>
  <!--...-->
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $bar; ?>" > //Logic is separated from markup
  <!--...-->
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know it i get realy your question. so if my answer not exaclty i will like to de  deleted

this class will create simple view

```
class View
{

public function render($filename, $render_without_header_and_footer = false)
{
    // page without header and footer, for whatever reason
    if ($render_without_header_and_footer == true) {
        require VIEWS_PATH . $filename . '.php';
    } else {
        require VIEWS_PATH . '_templates/header.php';
        require VIEWS_PATH . $filename . '.php';
        require VIEWS_PATH . '_templates/footer.php';
    }
}


private function checkForActiveController($filename, $navigation_controller)
{
    $split_filename = explode("/", $filename);
    $active_controller = $split_filename[0];

    if ($active_controller == $navigation_controller) {
        return true;
    }
    // default return
    return false;
}

private function checkForActiveAction($filename, $navigation_action)
{
    $split_filename = explode("/", $filename);
    $active_action = $split_filename[1];

    if ($active_action == $navigation_action) {
        return true;
    }
    // default return of not true
    return false;
}

private function checkForActiveControllerAndAction($filename, $navigation_controller_and_action)
{
    $split_filename = explode("/", $filename);
    $active_controller = $split_filename[0];
    $active_action = $split_filename[1];

    $split_filename = explode("/", $navigation_controller_and_action);
    $navigation_controller = $split_filename[0];
    $navigation_action = $split_filename[1];

    if ($active_controller == $navigation_controller AND $active_action == $navigation_action) {
        return true;
    }
    // default return of not true
    return false;
}
}
```

soo now you can create your templates and can call it from any where just like

```
$this->view->my_data = "data";
$this->view->render('index/index');
//
```

and on your index/index.php you can call the data $this->my_data;