# If I don't use a template engine with my PHP, what should my code look like?

Tags: php, templates

I don't want to use an MVC framework.  I don't want to use a template engine.  I am a few man shop where the developers where all the hats, no graphic artists.  We do it all (all layers).  I do not want code mixed with presentation, like I have with Classic ASP.

But, I do not know what my code is suppose to look like between server side and the actual presentation.

If I'm not emitting HTML in my server side code, how does it get to the HTML page so I can do things like `<span><?= $myvar ?></span>`? and put loops in the html page?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: MVC is a good starting point, whether you use a framework or not.

Comment: I know but I don't always have the luxury of making everyone do that, even it is the right way.

Comment: You don't really have the luxury of not doing it, since proper separation of concerns speeds up modifications and debugging tremendously. You will spend 90% of your time in debugging and maintenance, only 10% in initial coding - ask yourself where you want your savings.

Comment: @johnny If you can't make everyone do what you want them to do, there's not much point in asking for best practices here ;-)

Comment: @jeroen I was hoping I could at least make things more palatable.

Comment: Might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229532/creating-views-in-php-best-practice/6229791#6229791

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For using loops and all, I use the alternative syntax for the control structures.

An example:

```
<div id="messages"<?php if(!(isset($messages) && count($messages))): ?> class="hidden"<?php endif; ?>>
    <?php if(isset($messages)): ?>
    <?php foreach($messages as $message): ?>
    <div class="message"><?php echo $message; ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

For more information, see this: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Oh also, I use a semi-MVC structure, where I have a class that handles templates (views), basically it's just a class that I create an instance of, pass a set of variables, then render the template when the instance get destroyed. I have an array of variables in that  class, and then use extract to pass all variables in the include, like so:

```
extract($this->variables, EXTR_SKIP);
include($this->file);
```

EDIT: Here is the same example in Smarty:

```
<div id="messages"{if isset($messages) && !count($messages)} class="hidden"{/if}>
    {if isset($messages)}
    {foreach from=$messages item=message}
    <div class="message">{$message}</div>
    {/foreach}
    {/if}
</div>
```

Comment: templating engines are looking good at this moment.  This looks incredibly difficult to maintain.

Comment: As a comment said - PHP *is* a templating system. Its problem is that it's a bit too good at doing other things too, so people, especially beginners, end up mixing a lot of business code into the presentation layer, which is the real problem - not any code in the presentation layer. What jValdron wrote is a rather nice template, as templates go, and a dedicated template system would not help all that much, IMHO. The biggest benefit PHP gets from templating engines is that they restrict what you can do in presentation, crippling overeager coders.

Comment: I used Smarty before, and let me tell you, it's an even bigger pain in the arse... first of, it slows down my code by at least 2 times, and secondly, you have to learn a new syntax.

Comment: @johnny to be fair, the above isn't indented right. you can also use `<? ?>` instead of `<?php ?>`, you can also use `<?= $var ?>` instead of `<?php echo $var; ?>`.

Comment: Check my edit, I've included a Smarty exemple of the same file

Comment: php is a templating engine by itself in a way.

Comment: @dqhendricks I don't use the shorthand PHP declaration because it doesn't work will all servers, most of them, but it must be set in php.ini

Comment: @jValdron that smarty template looks just as difficult.  thanks for showing me.

Comment: @jValdron true, but it makes things much clearer. I would assume you typically have control of whatever server you are using unless it is like a distributed open source product or something.

Comment: @jValdron I wish I knew more of how you did things with the semi-mvc.  Maybe there is a link that demonstrates it somewhere, some tutorial out there?

Comment: @dqhendricks I usually develop websites on my development server then push it out on clients server, which I have no idea what it will be, and with hosts like GoDaddy and crap like them, I prefer not to rely on the fact that their servers are correctly setup, but I do see your point of view :)

Comment: @johnny Unfortunately, I pretty much developed everything myself, so I'm not saying that it's the best way, far from that. However, I use the principals of the MVC, but not as strongly type, I do not define every models, I have a layer on top of PDO, that makes getting information easier. For my views, I already explained a bit. As for the controllers, pretty much everything are pages, but I have some classes in my framework that acts like controllers. I don't mind sharing some code, however, it's really meant to be use with all my framework.

Answer (score 2):

Simple PHP projects usually generate the full HTML in-place instead of populating templates, so you'd just `echo` it out in your PHP code.

This gets messy, so you WILL end up coding some kind of templating system for any moderately complex website.

A possible alternative is to serve your page as completely static HTML/CSS and use AJAX to fetch the actual contents dynamically (JSON would be a good transport format, it's native to JS and can easily be generated from PHP). This gets you rid of all the HTML littered across your PHP code. Whether this is a viable alternative or not depends on the case.

Answer (score 1):

`<span><?= $myvar ?></span>` works.

A loop would look like:

```
<html>
 <body>

<?php
 for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
   {
   echo "The number is " . $i . "<br />";
   }
 ?>

</body>
 </html>
```

Example taken from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp).

Comment: man, that's ugly.  Not you, just thinking it sure looks bad, as in design bad.

Comment: LMAO, thanks buddy.  I'm not a web developer, so it looks beautiful to me. :)

Comment: I didn't mean it against you.  I just meant I didn't expect that and it looks a whole lot like what I do now.  I just didn't expect it.  Thanks.

Comment: IMHO, that's the best way to acheive "inline php" and as far as being pretty, it's actually very similar to "state-of-the-art" Microsoft MVC Razor syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend that you use the [php Template Inheritance](http://phpti.com/) system. (*Don't let it scare you, it's only one file*.) This is a simple set of functions that helps you to build extensible PHP views without the problems and limitations of manual includes.

It's still Pure PHP, so you don't need to learn some strange template language. It may not look like much, but it's really powerful once you start using it.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, you *can* do it all by yourself - but what you want is still MVC pattern, or separation of concerns ("I do not want code mixed with presentation"). Or at least MV, for very simple applications (although it's still dirty, having models directly influence the view).

The easiest way to achieve this is to first collect and process all data, then just print them. No complex code allowed in the php files directly exposed to the web.

```
<?php
  require('model.inc');
  process_capuchin_monkey_order_form();
?>
...
<h1>Thank you for your order of <?php echo $order->num_monkeys; ?> monkeys.</h1>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

typically you would want to just make sure you have as little PHP in your HTML as possible. This means doing all of the data processing before hand, and simply passing a set of variables in one way or another to a method or function that includes the HTML.

Any HTML with PHP intermixed could be considered a template. Here's a simplified example:

```
// view class

class View {

   public function render($html_template) {
      include('view_path/' . $html_template . '.php');
   }
}

// html template file 'view_path/main.php'

<html>
   <body>
      <h1><?= $this->title ?></h1>
   </body>
</html>

// usage

$view = new View();
$view->title = 'Some Title';
$view->render('main');
```

Comment: while you want as little PHP in your HTML, you would definitely not want to have any HTML in any of your PHP code. becomes very messy.

Comment: you could also use __set() magic method to only allow for already defined properties to be set in the view class. this takes a little extra setup, but prevent people from setting the wrong properties etc. you could take this a step further and check all properties during render to make sure that all defined properties have been set. a million ways you could go with this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an MVC-like separation of concerns no matter what you do. This means:

1. At least one file is all html and is given a handful of variables. (view/template)
2. At least one file is all php and only talks to the database. (model)
3. At least one file processes the http request, pulls data from database, and executes the view.

The core of every php templating language is the use of `extract()` and `include` inside a function:

```
function render_template($___filename, $___data) {
    extract($___data, EXTR_SKIP);
    include $__filename;
}
```

You can pretty this up with a class interface (view objects) or with output buffering, but this is the core of every template system.  Your controller's responsibility is simply to assemble that `$__data` argument (usually with data from a database) for a given view.